# I can not use "this.props.form"

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, antd

sorry I am a beginner for react.
if I mistake any word or thinking, understand plz.

I make a project with VS2017 react template. 
and adding the antd from npm. 
I am testing about the antd form but i see the error. 
"(TS) 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly>' can not find 'form' attribute. "

My source is

```
import { RounteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
....
export class Test extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
    ....

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields(.....);
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Comment: the code that you provided isn't enough to answer your question. What is your `this.props.form` inside your component?

Comment: @MatheusReis I want to get data from antd item(ex select). so i check antd form example. but i can not use "this.props.form" object because the error "not found 'form' attribute in 'this.props'"

Comment: you need to find a way to access the form. The form is a children of the component above? This code isn't enough to understand your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [ant-design document](https://ant.design/components/form/):

> If the form has been decorated by `Form.create` then it has `this.props.form` property.

So, you need to add `Form.create` in your component as below:

```
class CustomizedForm extends React.Component {}

CustomizedForm = Form.create({})(CustomizedForm);
```